# jquery chosen dropdown update

Tags: jquery, sql, jquery-chosen

I created a Form select dropdown list which is populated from a sql database.
sql table rows are: Last_Name, First_Name, eMail and ID.

```
echo'<div>';
echo'<select data-placeholder="Select Contact..." class="chosen-select3" style="width:380px;" tabindex="0" name="acc_contact" id="acc_contact">';
echo'<option value=""></option>';

//----- get contact from table Contacts

$my_query="(SELECT * FROM `Contacts` ORDER BY `Contact_Last_Name` ASC)";
$my_result = mysqli_query($con,$my_query);
while ($my_row = mysqli_fetch_array($my_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $contact_options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"".$my_row["id"]."\">".$my_row["Contact_First_Name"]." ".$my_row["Contact_Last_Name"]."</OPTION>"."\n";
}

echo $contact_options;
echo '</select>';    
echo '</div>';
```

Everything works fine, but how can I add a New account to the dropdown List?

For example: New Contact should be Jane Doe, jd@acme_new.com.

My Idea was to open an input form which asks the complete data (First,-Lastname & email) and add the Name to the dropdown list.

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
  no_results_text: "Name not found" 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<div>
  <select data-placeholder="Select Contact Name..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">John Doe</option>
    <option value="2">Jane Unknown</option>
    <option value="3">Jim Smith</option>
  </select>    
</div>
```

Comment: you want to add an new option to dropdown?

Comment: Yes, something like a "+add Name" at the end of the List.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I found the solution. There are 2 different forks of jquery.choosen. If I use the Version: koenpunt/chosen it works. It doesn't work with the Chosen (v1.8.7) from harvesthq.

[Koenpunt fork of chosen](https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen/releases/tag/v1.8.3).

The new script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 $(document).ready(function () {   
  $('.chosen-select').chosen({   
    create_option: true,   
    persistent_create_option: true,  
    skip_no_results: true,   
    create_option_text: 'add Contact'    
  });    
  });    
</script>
```